# Documentation of OptaPlanner Accumulate Functions like sum(), accumulate, list() etc..?

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I can't find the API or any documentation listing the drools Accumulate Functions like sum(), accumulate, list() etc..

Can someone post the URL.  I looked for a long time on the site and Google.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally found it, as Optaplanner and Drools are not the same, moreover two separate projects under the same umbrella.

https://drools.org/learn/documentation.html

Section 8:
https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.6.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_keywords